Влияние счётчиков Яндекс Метрики на показатели Page Speed
У меня есть сайт битрикс на котором настроены счётчики Яндекс Метрики И mail.ru. Если прогнать страницу через Page Speed, то он сильно ругается на эти счётчики и за счёт этого сильно занижает баллы по производительности, в частности показатель TBT. Подскажите, как мне можно вынести скрипты этих метрик, чтоб они не нагружали общий поток. Стоит мне только убрать скрипт одной из метрик, так количество баллов прям кратно возрастает. Вот собственно скрипт.
<script type="text/javascript">
    window.addEventListener('load', function() {
    (function (m, e, t, r, i, k, a) {
        m[i] = m[i] || function () {
            (m[i].a = m[i].a || []).push(arguments)
        };
        m[i].l = 1 * new Date();
        for (var j = 0; j < document.scripts.length; j++) {
            if (document.scripts[j].src === r) {
                return;
            }
        }
        k = e.createElement(t), a = e.getElementsByTagName(t)[0], k.async = 1, k.src = r, a.parentNode.insertBefore(k, a)
    (window, document, "script", "https://mc.yandex.ru/metrika/tag.js", "ym");
    ym(40772144, "init", {
        clickmap: true,
        trackLinks: true,
        accurateTrackBounce: true,
        webvisor: true
    });
});
});

Пытался также ставить атрибут async скрипту, но это тоже ничего не дало. Слышал еще про воркеры, но неужели это единственный вариант?


А что слышали про Worker'ы? Как они эту ситуацию исправляют?

Можно попробовать сделать "отложенную" загрузку метрик, допустим через 3-5-10 секунд после открытия.

Гиблое это дело бороться с Page Speed. Он дебил не всегда понимает, что это не возможно сделать. Даже если вы в pageSpeed загрузите страницу google.com - он и там найдёт что нужно улучшать, то есть скажет, что слишком долгая загрузка изображения)). Я сделал сайт одному магазину и PageSpeed показывал 80+, но они захотели Facebook Pixel, Yandex Metrika, Google Analytics, JIVO site и прочую лабуду из-за которой pageSpeed начал показывать 29.

Можно отложенную загрузку метрики делать. Вот хороший пример:
<script type="text/javascript">
            ( function () {
                'use strict';
 
                // Флаг, что Метрика уже загрузилась.
                var loadedMetrica = false,
                    // Ваш идентификатор сайта в Яндекс.Метрика.
                    metricaId     = 123456789,
                    // Переменная для хранения таймера.
                    timerId;
 
                // Для бота Яндекса грузим Метрику сразу без "отложки",
                // чтобы в панели Метрики были зелёные кружочки
                // при проверке корректности установки счётчика.
                if ( navigator.userAgent.indexOf( 'YandexMetrika' ) > -1 ) {
                    loadMetrica();
                } else {
                    // Подключаем Метрику, если юзер начал скроллить.
                    window.addEventListener( 'scroll', loadMetrica, {passive: true} );
 
                    // Подключаем Метрику, если юзер коснулся экрана.
                    window.addEventListener( 'touchstart', loadMetrica );
 
                    // Подключаем Метрику, если юзер дернул мышкой.
                    document.addEventListener( 'mouseenter', loadMetrica );
 
                    // Подключаем Метрику, если юзер кликнул мышкой.
                    document.addEventListener( 'click', loadMetrica );
 
                    // Подключаем Метрику при полной загрузке DOM дерева,
                    // с "отложкой" в 1 секунду через setTimeout,
                    // если пользователь ничего вообще не делал (фоллбэк).
                    document.addEventListener( 'DOMContentLoaded', loadFallback );
                }
 
                function loadFallback() {
                    timerId = setTimeout( loadMetrica, 1000 );
                }
 
                function loadMetrica( e ) {
 
                    // Пишем отладку в консоль браузера.
                    if ( e && e.type ) {
                        console.log( e.type );
                    } else {
                        console.log( 'DOMContentLoaded' );
                    }
 
                    // Если флаг загрузки Метрики отмечен,
                    // то ничего более не делаем.
                    if ( loadedMetrica ) {
                        return;
                    }
 
                    (function(m,e,t,r,i,k,a){m[i]=m[i]||function(){(m[i].a=m[i].a||[]).push(arguments)}; m[i].l=1*new Date();k=e.createElement(t),a=e.getElementsByTagName(t)[0],k.async=1,k.src=r,a.parentNode.insertBefore(k,a)}) (window, document, "script", "https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/yandex-metrica-watch/tag.js", "ym");
                    ym( metricaId, "init", { clickmap:true, trackLinks:true, accurateTrackBounce:true });
 
                    // Отмечаем флаг, что Метрика загрузилась,
                    // чтобы не загружать её повторно при других
                    // событиях пользователя и старте фоллбэка.
                    loadedMetrica = true;
 
                    // Очищаем таймер, чтобы избежать лишних утечек памяти.
                    clearTimeout( timerId );
 
                    // Отключаем всех наших слушателей от всех событий,
                    // чтобы избежать утечек памяти.
                    window.removeEventListener( 'scroll', loadMetrica );
                    window.removeEventListener( 'touchstart', loadMetrica );
                    document.removeEventListener( 'mouseenter', loadMetrica );
                    document.removeEventListener( 'click', loadMetrica );
                    document.removeEventListener( 'DOMContentLoaded', loadFallback );
                }
            } )()
    </script>

Источник: https://www.kobzarev.com/technical-seo/yandex-metrika-lazy-load
